# Error when using helm setup with use-package

Tags: helm, use-package, error

My current helm configuration is

```
(use-package helm
  :bind (("M-x" . helm-M-x)
         ("C-x b" . helm-mini)
         ("C-x C-f" . helm-find-files)
         ("C-x C-d" . helm-browse-project)
         ("M-y" . helm-show-kill-ring))
  )
(helm-mode 1)
(setq helm-M-x-fuzzy-match 1)
(setq helm-buffers-fuzzy-matching 1)
(setq helm-recentf-fuzzy-match    1)
```

This works, but I wish it were more idiomatic. If I try to put the trailing commands in `:config`, like so:

```
(use-package helm
  :bind (("M-x" . helm-M-x)
         ("C-x b" . helm-mini)
         ("C-x C-f" . helm-find-files)
         ("C-x C-d" . helm-browse-project)
         ("M-y" . helm-show-kill-ring))
  :config ((helm-mode 1)
           (setq helm-M-x-fuzzy-match 1)
           (setq helm-buffers-fuzzy-matching 1)
           (setq helm-recentf-fuzzy-match 1))
  )
```

I get the error `Error (use-package): helm/:config: Invalid function: (helm-mode 1)`. **Does anyone know what's going on here?**

For reference, I'm using Emacs 28.2 on Ubuntu 22.10 with straight.el, and use-package is configured to use straight by default, like so:

```
(use-package straight
  :custom (straight-use-package-by-default t))
```

Comment: [This reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/zmg16j/how_to_configure_helm_after_recent_update_using/j43o21s/) describes some things I tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:config` clause has too many parens and should read:

```lisp
(use-package helm
  :bind (("M-x" . helm-M-x)
         ("C-x b" . helm-mini)
         ("C-x C-f" . helm-find-files)
         ("C-x C-d" . helm-browse-project)
         ("M-y" . helm-show-kill-ring))
  :config  (helm-mode 1)
           (setq helm-M-x-fuzzy-match 1)
           (setq helm-buffers-fuzzy-matching 1)
           (setq helm-recentf-fuzzy-match 1)
  )
```

In your version, emacs evaluates a list whose first entry it expects to be a function (as it always does) but gets `(helm-mode 1)` instead.

Comment: Yep, that seems to have been the issue. Thanks!